# Is Membase, the windows port of memcache on top of a no-sql repository a stable and solid product

Tags: memcached, membase

Is Membase, the windows port of memcache on top of a no-sql repository a stable and solid product?   Does anyone have any experience good or bad?  How widely supported it the product, it seems like a great product, I wonder if they have much adoption?

Comment: If you're going to down vote - at least have the courtesy so the OP and other potential new comers know why....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membase is well supported and documented. Forum posts on their website are usually responded to in a day or two. As for adoption, Membase runs under a number of Zynga's social games and is used by AOL for it's advertising platform. If you want production support outside of the forums Couchbase the creator of Membase provide 12x5 and 24x7 support.